# Change of basis and similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the transformation $T$ in the standard basis:

$$[T]_B\begin{bmatrix} 0&3&1 \\ -1&3&1 \\ 0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Also consider the two matrices:

$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&-4 \\ 0&4&-1 \\ 1&1&-2 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1 \\ -1&2&1 \\ 0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

> Prove that there's is no basis $A$ such that $[T]_A = A_i$ where $i=1,2$.

So basically the answer is:
for $i=1$: $\text{trace}([T]_B) \ne \text{trace}(A_1) $ and for $i=2$: $\det([T]_B) \ne \det(A_1) $, and therefore, there is no such $A$.

I can infer that a change of basis keeps the matrices similar. Is that the theorem behind this exercise?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course: well done +1. In fact, **that** is the very linear-algebraic definition of similarity: two matrices are similar iff they represent the very same linear transformation wrt two different basis. And this keeps invariant both trace and determinant...and some other stuff, too.